# Update a column value, replacing part of a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns in a MySQL database

```
[id, url]
```

And the URLs are like:

```
 http://domain1.example/images/img1.jpg
```

I want to update all the URLs to another domain

```
 http://domain2.example/otherfolder/img1.jpg
```

keeping the name of the file as is.

What's the query must I run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL string replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

Answer (score 938, accepted):

```
UPDATE urls
SET url = REPLACE(url, 'domain1.example/images/', 'domain2.example/otherfolder/')
```

Comment: Watch the CaSiNg (ask me how I know!). :)

Comment: It's so awesome when MySQL can do such stuff out of the box so you don't need to manage it via server-side languages)

Answer (score 231):

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET url = REPLACE(url, 'http://domain1.example/images/', 'http://domain2.example/otherfolder/')
WHERE url LIKE ('http://domain1.example/images/%');
```

relevant docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Hi there- why do I need the where ?

Comment: @GuyCohen Because otherwise the query will modify every single row in the table. The `WHERE` clause optimizes the query to only modify the rows with certain URL. Logically, the result will be the same, but the addition of `WHERE` will make the operation faster.

Comment: The `WHERE` also ensures that you're only replacing parts of strings that _begin_ with `http://etc/etc/` or `string_to_be_replaced.` For example, in the given answer, `http://domain1.com/images/this/is/a/test` would be affected, but `foobar/http://domain1.com/images/` would not.

Comment: WHERE url LIKE - was very necessary for me, thanks

Answer (score 30):

Try using the [REPLACE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
mysql> SELECT REPLACE('www.example.com', 'w', 'Ww');
        -> 'WwWwWw.example.com'
```

Note that it is case sensitive.

Comment: @UniversalGrasp See a lot of possible answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656056/case-insensitive-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 17):

Try this...

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] = 
replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

Comment: Exact answer, What am looking for.

Answer (score 10):

You need the **WHERE** clause to replace **ONLY** the records that complies with the condition in the WHERE clause (as opposed to all records). You use **%** sign to indicate partial string: I.E.

```
LIKE ('...//example.com/images/%');
```

means all records that **BEGIN** with `"...//example.com/images/"` and have anything AFTER (that's the `%` for...)

Another example:

```
LIKE ('%http://example.com/images/%')
```

which means all records that contains `"http://example.com/images/"`

in any part of the string...

Answer (score 4):

**First, have to check**

```
SELECT * FROM `university` WHERE course_name LIKE '%&amp%'
```

**Next, have to update**

```
UPDATE university
SET course_name = REPLACE(course_name, '&amp', '&') WHERE id = 1
```

**Results:** Engineering &amp Technology => **Engineering & Technology**