# Replace html break with ACSI return in mysql memo field

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that contains a couple of MEMO field types that have text that contains html break tags (`<br />`)

I want to globally remove these tags and insert a new line in the memo field at this point (I believe this is the ascii 10 character)

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: @stark I don't know how to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a column value, replacing part of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string)

Comment: @CasWolters it is not a duplicate as that is asking how to replace one part of a string with another string, I want to replace part of a string with a non visible control character

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace statement:

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, '<br/>', '\r\n');
```

The string representation of a new line/linefeed is \n and \r. You can use one or both according to your needs.