# SQL Updating column in records where only part of content is to be changed

Tags: mysql, sql

In table XXX I have a column YYY with links:

> htttp://mysiteddress/items/cat32/2a.pdf
>   htttp://mysiteddress/items/cat32/3a.pdf
>   htttp://mysiteddress/items/cat32/4a.pdf
>   .
>   .
>   .

I want to make a query that change cat32 into cat22 but I have no idea how to do that. Could anybody help me?

I assume it should be made somehow with UPDATE query...

Comment: Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as is this is off topic for multiple reasons!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a column value, replacing part of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string)

Comment: How is it unclear what tapitap is asking?

Comment: I think it's about title. I have changed it. Got -1 after my first post... One more post and I will be put to prison :P Anyway thank you guys for help. I checked your solutions and though they seem reasonable they don't work. But maybe I just do something wrong or there is other cause so I wrote to my host support. I hope they will tell me what to do about that.

Comment: I was going to post here a solution unfortunately I didn't get any useful information from host support. If I solve somehow the problem I will tell what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
UPDATE XXX SET YYY = REPLACE(YYY, 'cat32', 'cat22')
```

Comment: Ok, now this works :) I have no idea why it didn't work but after my contact with host everything is ok. Thank you very much. Unfortunately I cannot give you any point as my reputation is too low...

Comment: Hey @tapitap, you should be able to accept my question by clicking the checkmark to the left if you feel like it is the best answer. Cheers!

Comment: Done :) I can do something similar for powermock, but I don't know how. His link is useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce that result for you:

```
UPDATE XXX SET YYY = REPLACE(YYY, 'cat32', 'cat22')
```

but it will also replace

```
htttp://mysiteddress/items/cat32/2cat32a.pdf
```

to

```
htttp://mysiteddress/items/cat22/2cat22a.pdf
```

which might not be needed so in that case to support preg replace in mysql use `lib_mysqludf_preg` library