# how to remove special character in database?

Tags: mysql

How to convert `Banksâ€™` to bank's in db. all records to add `Banksâ€™` like this. how can print with `Banksâ€™` in screen.

Comment: What's the collation on the table and the field? Looks and feels like an encoding problem.

Comment: no no automatically add plural word. how to remove in db.

Comment: You can use html_entity_decode to convert special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 SELECT REPLACE('Banksâ€™', 'sâ€™', ''\s') from table_name
```

Comment: i have 1000 records how can know that particular word? example that word Banksâ€™' ask to u. in my database bank's and college's this are convert and store Banksâ€™',college€™' like this. how to remove all records in my database...?

Comment: Okay...
What is the common string attached to the strings due to collation problem? is it just e€™? If 'Yes' the above query can be modified.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string

This may be helpful for you :)

Comment: am retrieving data in ajax this character inside db means cannot load ajax function how to solve this problem

Comment: Okay.. Let me try with it. If I get the solution; shall Tell you :)

Comment: s i modified but not working ajax function i give like this remove all collation. bank words how to remove another words. how to stop collation adding in db? SELECT REPLACE('Banksâ€™', 'sâ€™', '\s') from table_name