# Mysql can't update the data

Tags: php, mysql

When i try to execute the code below it shows the error:
**Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','','','')' at line 1**

```
$result = mysql_query("REPLACE INTO templates (id,title,subtitle,background,image,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,createdby) VALUES ('$id','$title','$subtitle','$background','$image','$image2','$image3','$image4,'$image5','$image6','$fbuid')");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

But the code below works totally fine:

```
mysql_query("REPLACE INTO Users (fbuid,username,email,token) VALUES ('$fbuid', '$name', '$email', '$token')");
```

**What can be the issue?**

Comment: you can refer to the earlier post to update data 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string

Hope this help you.

Comment: I have asked myself this too many times, perhaps you can comment below. Why are you using `mysql_*()` functions?

Comment: if `$id` is your primary key you need not to insert it you can leave it as a blank like this `mysql_query("REPLACE INTO templates (id,title,subtitle,background,image,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,createdby) VALUES (' ','$title','$subtitle','$background','$image','$image2','$image3','$image4,'$image5','$image6','$fbuid')");`

Comment: @EaBangalore Let me rephrase the question. Why are you using `mysql_query()`

Comment: I am being ignored here, once again. Its like "questioneers" know using `mysql_query()` is wrong, but they tend to go around it in a huge freaking circle (diameter of Jupiter) and ignore every comment on it.

Comment: @Xorifelse i fell your pain

Comment: @Dagon Let's share it together :)

Comment: @Xorifelse If only the PHP manual had a giant warning somewhere that could alert people to the fact that these functions have been deprecated for years..... [oh wait](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was missing a `'` sign after `$image4`… problem solved.

Comment: *Please* do not wildly put user data into SQL statements as you have done, it is an obvious potential security hole. If $title comes from a user and contains an apostrophe, they can break out of your SQL and e.g. potentially delete your entire database. Please read the PHP manual on how to use placeholders, e.g. using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php (or PDO version) or if you must, mysql_real_escape_string.