# remove text before certain character phpmyadmin mysql database

Tags: mysql

I want to remove all text before the "@"
 in  table "food", column "names"

For example:

123@apple
890@orange

so the result will be just

apple
orange

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to update a particular column in some table of a database.
[You may try this to replace a substring in a column for each record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string)

Comment: I didn't find a solution in the link provided. all the text I want to remove in each row is different.