# MYSQL query to update for date field

Tags: mysql, replace

I need to update a date column value replace some string in replace the same value to date column.

Ex:
Now date field have '2017-06-12 05:05:05' this value i need to replace this value to '2017-06-12'

I need query like update query

```
UPDATE student SET student_name = replace(student_name, 'John', 'Mark');
```

Comment: Its already in stackoverflow...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 cast('2017-06-12 05:05:05' AS DATE)
```

> output :-  2017-06-12

**If you want replace then try this**

```
 trim(replace('2017-06-12 05:05:05','05:05:05',''))
```

> output :-  2017-06-12

Answer (score 1):

Simply use CAST with UPDATE statement. Just insert your col name. You can cast field value to another type and assign to this field easily.

```
UPDATE
    student
SET
    <col_name> = CAST(<col_name> AS DATE)
WHERE
    <condition>
```