# Unable to process a code with special character

Tags: mysql, sql-update, special-characters

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` 
SET 
`description` = REPLACE(`description`, '<li><p>', '<li>')
```

Above code is not processing and says `0 Rows affected`, however, the following code is working with some rows affected:

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` 
SET 
`description` = REPLACE(`description`, 'lip', 'li')
```

How do I process the previous code? I want to replace exactly `<li><p>`

Comment: I've tested your query and it seems to be fine. Could it be that your table doesn't really have that `'<li><p>'` value?

Comment: I had the same problem in my php app, I just add to remove the strip_tags() function in my model.

Comment: @Maxime I need to update these strings.

Comment: @tcadidot0 These values are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is similar to this. You may take a look at it:

[Update a column value, replacing part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string)

I think you may want to add the `LIKE` and `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` query. Something like this: `UPDATE yourtable
SET url = REPLACE(url, 'http://domain1.com/images/', 'http://domain2.com/otherfolder/')
WHERE url LIKE ('http://domain1.com/images/%');`

Comment: I dont think WHERE and LIKE are needed as I want to process it for all the rows.

Comment: did you try to look up on the link I gave you and tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the `description` value doesn't be encoded by any encoding.

Or you can try to replace `<` with `&lt;` and replace `>` with `&gt;`

Comment: the description is not encoded by any encoding & replacing < with &lt; and replace > with &gt; doesn't work either as the strings need to be searched.

Comment: Where did you executed the SQL? In a console or in a program?

Answer (score 0):

Below query working fine for me.

`UPDATE s_demo SET  description = REPLACE(description,'<li><p>','<b>222<b>') WHERE id = 1`

- I think one thing need to check description field **Collation** type. In my case i used **Collation = utf8_general_ci**
- I hope, this is to help you

Comment: Collation = utf8_general_ci for the table. The query is not working.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake, with other collation type working fine for me. see in below screen shot.
https://www.screencast.com/t/0cmWQxkwO