# Update column, replace part of value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to replace a specific piece of text. I have no experience at all with mysql.

The table (content) has a column ( keywords ) containing all kind of words separated by comma. I want to replace *tekst* with *text*. 

**Important:** the whole string contains many other combined values with partly *tekst* in it which i DO NOT want to replace.

Example: ***tekst***, tekst one, tekst two, teksting, foo, bar, should be replaced by ***text***, tekst one, tekst two, teksting, foo, bar,

I tried this but it replaced all by only text and erased the rest

```
UPDATE content
SET keywords=text
WHERE keywords=tekst;
```

Comment: Use replace, plz go through tutorials if you are new
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-string-replace-function.aspx/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update a column value, replacing part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string)

Comment: @billyonecan It does not unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```sql
UPDATE content
SET    keywords = REPLACE(keywords, 'tekst', 'text')
WHERE  keywords LIKE '%tekst%'
```

Comment: It's close. 
I should have mentioned in my post that I only want to replace tekst and not other keywords that have "tekst" in it. 

So when I want to replace tekst in tekst, tekst1, tekst2, weather, sun, moon it should only replace tekst and leave tekst1 and tekst2 as is.