# How to add extra folder to multiple paths stored in MySQL database? From `Folder\file.jpg` to `Folder\New Folder\file.jpg`?

Tags: mysql

**Details:**

I have stored physical paths into MySQL table. I have moved all content to a new folder.

**This is the data in the database:**

```
Current data---

g:\Folder1\File 1.jpg
g:\Folder1\Excel File.xlsx
g:\Folder1\Test.js
```

**Desired change:**

Here is what I'd like to achieve, add an extra folder to the path before the filename.

```
Desired---

g:\Folder1\New Folder\File 1.jpg
g:\Folder1\New Folder\Excel File.xlsx
g:\Folder1\New Folder\Test.js
```

**Question**

How can I achieve this? And just for future, how can I remove a specific folder from the path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use REPLACE as explained also in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177208/update-a-column-value-replacing-part-of-a-string)

```
UPDATE table
SET fied = REPLACE(field, 'g:\Folder1\', 'g:\Folder1\New Folder\')
```

It is untested so you may have to fix the `\` escaping

Since REPLACE gives you the ability to replace the string with another one you can just modify the strings to "add or remove folders"

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function:

```
SELECT replace(filename, "Folder1\\", "Folder1\\New Folder\\")
FROM your_table;
```

You can specify a path from drive letter to avoid random data being replaced.

Comment: this will just display the updated data. It will not update them in the database

Comment: Sure, but it gives a way to do anything with this new path - to store it or to just displa.