# how to edit my links (sort and change by starting alphabet) in sql database

Tags: mysql

i have a database (mysql) with links like:

```
mysite.com/Movies/Abajan_1080p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/Abajan_720p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/Abajan_480p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/Bahman_1080p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/Bahman_720p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/Bahman_480p.mp4
```

....
i sorted my files by creating directories by alphabets (A,B,...)
so i need to change links:

```
mysite.com/Movies/A/Abajan_1080p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/A/Abajan_720p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/A/Abajan_480p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/B/Bahman_1080p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/B/Bahman_720p.mp4  
mysite.com/Movies/B/Bahman_480p.mp4
```

is there a simple solution to edit database? to edit all links like that?
Thanks a lot

Comment: All the values start with `mysite.com/Movies/` and are followed by the file name or there other folders and subfolders?

Comment: yes all movies links start with mysite.com/Movies/ , and then file name like this: Movies/Abajan_1080p.mp4

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Duplicate of [Update a column value, replacing part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10177208/90527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the filename and then concatenate the path:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col = CONCAT(
  'mysite.com/Movies/',
  LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '/', -1), 1),
  '/',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '/', -1)
)
```

Replace `col` with your column's name.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=32fd7d909e5ecaaeb99e753ad069ed24).
Results:

| col |
| --- |
| mysite.com/Movies/A/Abajan_1080p.mp4 |
| mysite.com/Movies/A/Abajan_720p.mp4 |
| mysite.com/Movies/A/Abajan_480p.mp4 |
| mysite.com/Movies/B/Bahman_1080p.mp4 |
| mysite.com/Movies/B/Bahman_720p.mp4 |
| mysite.com/Movies/B/Bahman_480p.mp4 |