# Case insensitive mysql replace

Tags: mysql, case

I have a text college in my table. When I search this text using autocomplete, I need to display this text as college with underline. Mysql replace() is using currently. But it is case sensitive. I want to make this case insensitive.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656056/case-insensitive-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `REPLACE(LOWER())`?

[MYSQL LOWER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower)

Comment: I already tried LOWER() .Yes it solves the issue.But search output is changing with my search keyword.Because of this a'm trying to find another solution.

Comment: Doesn't work because it will make the rest of the replaced value lowercase.